# Finding DVB-T Driver

Tags: driver

I have a DVB-T dongle which has following information:

```
  Product ID:   0x9016
  Vendor ID:    0x15a4  (Afa Technologies, Inc.)
```

After googling these information I found out the chip model used in this device: `Afatech AF9015`. I could not find a driver (even a generic one) for it, would you know how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears [unlikely an OS X driver is available](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3358698?start=0&tstart=0) but you may have success with Linux.

You could use a virtual machine such as VMWare Fusion or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) to test the approaches linked below:

> ## [Television with Linux](http://linuxtv.org)
>
> The LinuxTV community develops and maintains the Linux Kernel Media Subsystems and several userspace libraries and applications.
>
> The Linux Kernel Media Subsystems provides support for devices like webcams, streaming capture and output, analog TV, digital TV, AM/FM radio, Sofware Digital Radio (SDR) and remote controllers. It offers native support for a large number of drivers for commonly available PCI cards and USB devices, but the subsystems are also targeted towards Linux based set-top-boxes and embedded devices, like mobile phones.

- [Linux TV: Talk:Afatech AF9015](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Talk:Afatech_AF9015)
- [Can anybody help me to make Kworld UB445-Q TV tuner work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58547/can-anybody-help-me-to-make-kworld-ub445-q-tv-tuner-work)